# Exporting a large number of image variables in mathematical 11

Tags: export, string-manipulation, image, list-manipulation

I used the following code to import a large number of tiff images into notebook.

```
  SetDirectory[
  "C:\\My Files\\Shriram\\Paul 45deg 50%life 4x scan manual cs5.5 \
Tiff files"];
imagehl = FileNames["*.tiff"];
countgl = 1
 Do[imhl[countgl++] = Import[A0001], {A0001, imagehl}]
```

From the above code I got image variables with the names imhl[1], imhl[2] ect till imhl[968]
After this I performed some image processing on the files and saved them as imhl1[1], imh1l[2] ect till imhl1[968]
 Now I want to export all these images into a folder with similar names such as img1, img2 etc.. I tried using the following code but it does not seem to be working.

```
SetDirectory["C:\\My Files\\Shriram\\20x thick woven\\code\\export"];
counlt3 = 1;
counlt4 = 1;
Do[Export["img[" <> [counlt4++] <> "].jpg", imhl[counlt3++]], 968]
```

I am very new to Mathematica. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: you need to use `ToString[counlt4]`

Comment: Hello. Could you please explain further? I am not sure how to use the ToString in my arrays

Comment: where you have `[countl4++]` it is a syntax error, you need `ToString[countl4++]`